# Cascade @typeparam in Blazor

Tags: blazor

Can you somehow cascade the @typeparam ?

For instance in this scenario, pass the TItem to the Child without specifying it

Expected behavior:

```
<Parent TItem="User">
  <Child>
</Parent>
```

Current:

```
<Parent TItem="User">
  <Child TItem="User">
</Parent>
```

Comment: Perhaps state management might help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

Comment: It doesn't . No way to tell by using state management, that class Child<T> is actually Child<User>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, but it is supposed to be [coming with .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-2/#infer-component-generic-types-from-ancestor-components).

From the docs:

> In .NET 6 Preview 2, Blazor can now infer generic type parameters from ancestor components. Ancestor components must opt in to this behavior. An ancestor component can cascade a type parameter by name to descendants using the `[CascadingTypeParameter]` attribute. This attribute allows generic type inference to use the specified type parameter automatically with descendants that have a type parameter with the same name.

Comment: You might add https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#infer-generic-types-based-on-ancestor-components